# Best way to find and store difference between two strings

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, strings, substrings

I want to implement my version of the Codeshare service. Now I'm thinking of an implementation where all users have access to one string that can change (if you already have a better option here - please write about it).
What algorithms and data models are suitable to find the difference between two strings and to compactly store this difference, as well as to implement this difference in a string?
If my question isn't clear enough, please say so.

Comment: I voted to close your question as I believe it needs more focus. The SE platform is not suitable for open-ended discussion, but instead we like focused questions that have a clear concise answer. Could you describe more clearly what the problem is? What's the input, what's the desired output? What kind of distance are you thinking of - Hamming distance? How long are the strings?

Comment: Thank you, i will specify my question!

Comment: This looks an application/service/product/market definition question. When asking an appropriate audience, consider if just dropping the name *Codeshare* is enough to describe what you are after. You may be looking for [Edit distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance#Types_of_edit_distance) and [diff](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff).

Comment: @greybeard Sounds like an answer.